# grouping the rows and summation of the values on one column in python

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a big text file like this:

small example:

```
chr4    53382   53385   47  chr4    53382   53385   ZNF595  ENST00000509152.2   annotated
chr16   103500  103550  27  chr16   103475  103586  POLR3K  ENST00000293860.5   annotated
chr16   103550  103586  43  chr16   103475  103586  POLR3K  ENST00000293860.5   annotated
chr16   103584  103600  43  chr16   103584  104058  SNRNP25 ENST00000293861.3   annotated
chr16   103900  103950  37  chr16   103584  104058  SNRNP25 ENST00000293861.3   annotated
```

I want to group the rows based on the 8th column and sum the values of the 4th columns from the rows which belong the same group.

I have tried this code:

```
b = pd.read_csv("myfile.txt", sep='\t')
df = d.groupby(7)(3).sum()
df.to_csv('outfile.txt', sep='\t', index=None)


chr4    53382   53385   47  chr4    53382   53385   ZNF595  ENST00000509152.2   annotated
chr16   103550  103586  70  chr16   103475  103586  POLR3K  ENST00000293860.5   annotated
chr16   103584  103600  80  chr16   103584  104058  SNRNP25 ENST00000293861.3   annotated
```

Comment: What is your exact problem?

Comment: the problem is that, this code does not return the expected output

Comment: what _is_ the expected output?

Comment: It has summed the 4th column (47,  27+43,  43+37) and grouped on the 8th .... I don't get it.

Comment: if my solution worked for you, consider accepting it as an answer for future viewers.